# What does port forward website look like?

Tags: ethernet, port-forwarding

Is this a port forwarded website? I can only access it on some computer.
www.example.com:2041/

Does it use ethernet to use the site or it depends on the conputer?

Comment: Is that the actual website name? And also what makes you believe it is port-forwarded?

Answer (score 1):

When a URL contains a port number after the domain name or IP address (`http://domain:port/`), that means the server is running on a non-standard port. The default for unencrypted HTTP is 80 while the default for encrypted is 443. Depending on your ISP or the network you are using to access the Internet, non-default ports may not be allowed. While technically a computer's firewall settings could prohibit connecting to a non-standard HTTP port, if it does not work, the more likely cause is your ISP or the network's gateway firewall. If you use a proxy to access the Internet or Web, that proxy may impose further restrictions on which port numbers are allowed.

As for the server itself, a server administrator can usually choose pretty much any number between 1 and 65535 for an HTTP (Web) server to run on. Again, choosing a non-standard port requires that the number be specified on the URL since the browser would otherwise not know how to connect to the server. Whether a given port number works is not a matter of ethernet versus wireless or dial-up versus cable. The deciding factors are local and remote firewall, gateway, and proxy settings.

On the topic of port forwarding, the fact that a server uses a non-standard port really says nothing about whether the HTTP server is behind a proxy or port forwarding. A server using standard port numbers could possibly be behind port forwarding, just as a server on non-standard port numbers could be without any port forwarding. Any valid port number can be direct or forwarded.

To answer your main question, **you cannot tell whether a site is behind port forwarding based solely on its URL**. In fact, I am not familiar with any reliable method for detecting the use of port forwarding from the outside. Port forwarding is a relatively low-level type of routing that does not normally leave any artifacts in the HTTP communication. Your best option might be to use [TCP/IP fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting). For example, if the destination machine appears to be running Linux but the HTTP server is running Microsoft IIS, there is a good chance that port forwarding is being used.

Comment: This is mostly the answer I'd post - with less pictures. I'd add though linux needs root permissions to use low numbered ports (which is why many self contained webapps use high port numbers + a proxy of some sort) and many ISPs block block 80, 443, and well any other ports they feel like blocking for 'security' reasons.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek -- It should be clarified that when you say ISP's block port 80 and 443, you mean *incoming* port 80 and 443. Naturally any normal ISP will allow outgoing port 80 and 443. On low port numbers (under 1024) and permissions, I did not want to go into too much detail since the question seemed relatively elementary, but I am sure someone will want to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up 2 unrelated concepts here.   A port forwarded website looks exactly like a normal website.

Port forwarding is a routing technology, most often used when a web server is running off a simple network which uses NAT.  NAT is used by most consumer routers to share a single connection with a single IP address between multiple computers.

In this scenario, computers on the wider Internet can't know WHICH computer hosts the website - unless the router forwards the appropriate port on - and this is what port forwarding is.

The fact that a port other then 80 is being used has little to do with port forwarding (except when more then 1 computer behind NAT is running a web server).  Pretty much any port can be used for a web request - and often ports other then 80 are used to attain a level of security though obscurity, or because there is more then 1 web server running.

Nothing about the port number of whether port forwarding is used says anything about whether the connection is Ethernet or something else.